# MonoDroid ProgressDialog

Tags: android, xamarin.android

All I want to do is make sure the user knows that a webservice is processing so they don't repeatedly mash buttons while it tries to work.

```
        EditText partnumber = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.itemNumber);
        partnumber.FocusChange += (object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (!e.HasFocus)
            {
                var pd = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Processing", "Please Wait...", false);
                var res = new InventoryApp();
                res.partValidateCompleted += delegate { pd.Hide(); };
                var isValid = res.partValidate(partnumber.Text);
                if (isValid == "Not Found")
                {
                    partnumber.Text = "";
                    partnumber.RequestFocus();
                    partqty.ClearFocus();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.SetTitle("Invalid Part");
                    builder.SetMessage("Part number does not exist in database. Please ensure you are entering the correct part number and try again");
                    builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate { });
                    var dialog = builder.Create();
                    dialog.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    partdesc.Text = isValid;
                }
            }
        };
```

If I leave pd.Hide() in the code then I never see the progressdialog.  If I take it out, I only see the progressdialog after the webservice returns its results and then stays up because I haven't hidden it anywhere.   How do I get it to show while the app waits for partValidate and when can I hide it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from your code, it looks like the `partValidate()` method is synchronous. Since this code is being executed on the UI thread, the app's UI will be blocked for the duration of that method call, which would explain why you don't see any UI updates until it finishes. You could get around this by running the call on a background thread, and then moving back to the UI thread once you need to update the UI:

```
partnumber.FocusChange += (object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (!e.HasFocus)
    {
        var pd = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Processing", "Please Wait...", false);
        var res = new InventoryApp();
        res.partValidateCompleted += delegate { pd.Hide(); };

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        {
            var isValid = res.partValidate(partnumber.Text);

            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                if (isValid == "Not Found")
                {
                    partnumber.Text = "";
                    partnumber.RequestFocus();
                    partqty.ClearFocus();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.SetTitle("Invalid Part");
                    builder.SetMessage("Part number does not exist in database. Please ensure you are entering the correct part number and try again");
                    builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate { });
                    var dialog = builder.Create();
                    dialog.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    partdesc.Text = isValid;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I have a blog post up [here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/04/using-background-threads-in-mono-for-android-applications/) that explains various methods of dealing with this scenario on Mono for Android applications.

Comment: Seems to do the trick. Thanks!!  Would it be better for my webmethod to be asynchronous though or is this as or more efficient?

Comment: I'd say it's more a matter of which method makes the most sense for what you're doing rather than one of efficiency. Making the web call asynchronous can definitely be useful in cleaning up the code, but that means any client of that method needs to work asynchronously as well. Personally, for cases like this I like to make the call asynchronously, and pass in a delegate to the method for processing the results.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood from your question code in partValidate is async but there is no parameter for OnComplete callback. You can solve your problem adding it and your code will be something like this:

```
var isValid = res.partValidate(partnumber.Text,() => {pd.Hide();});
```

But the better way is to create implementation of `AsyncTask` class for you web service call.
Here you can find [demo](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/blob/master/MonoDroid/ThreadDemo/LoginTask.cs)

Comment: Seems like the issue is more with when the progressdialog shows than anything else. It doesn't appear until after partValidate runs.  I've added my full code just in case there is something obvious I am missing.